# Importing different Access Tables into Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

I have a large number of Access Databases with tables in different formats. I want to read a couple of specific tables from each Access DB and create the same format data in Sql. Clearly I can write code to do that, but I was wondering if it's possible to programmatically drive the Import wizard to do the same job.

To give an idea of the scale of the problem we're talking about 1000+ Access DBs with approximately 3 tables in each DB.

Answer (score 0):

use import/Export wizard of sqlserver.It has good capability and you can transfer any data from access to sqlserver easly.Just take care to Types which are supported in Access to Sql. Like you have to conver float in Access to Decimal in sql server you like that all you have to do is take care of DataType.

Comment: I was specifically looking for a code based solution, I don't want to manually import 1000 databases.

Comment: @mrTelly I am trying to find solution for same problem. Did you find anything ? thanks

Comment: I wrote my own assembly, based off a much extended version of this www.codeproject.com/Articles/17169/Copy-Data-from-a-DataTable-to-a-SQLServer-Database.